# Reporting Services WMI Provider error 8000000A

Tags: ssrs, wmi

I recently installed SQL Server Express 2005 with all available options.  When I run Start->Programs->SQL Server 2005->Reporting Services Configuration I get an error immediatley:

"An unknown error has occurred in the WMI Provider.  Error Code 8000000A"

I then cannot configure a reporting server.  Any suggestions for how to fix this issue?

EDIT: I am running running this on a Windows XP machine, and I have installed SQL Server 2005 Version 9.1.2047.00, which I believe is SP 1.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed SP2 or SP3 for SQL Server 2005? This is an issue with SP1 on Vista/2k8.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156468.aspx

From the afore mentioned website (around halfway down):

> Reporting Services SP1 and earlier do not run on Windows Vista. If you try to run an SP1 report server on Windows Vista, you will encounter: An unknown error has occurred in the WMI provider. Error Code 8000000A when using Reporting Services Configuration tool

NOTE: This quote has been modified from the original to narrow scope to your exact error.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this error disappears when you do things with administrative access.  I must have not had the right permissions.  Too bad the error message couldn't be a little more informative.